# How can I fake a global context to isolate tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

My unit tests are running in node.js (using mocha, chai, and sinon).  The code I'm testing is meant to be run in a browser.

Some of the code defines things globally while other code expects there to be a `window` object and it adds objects to `window`. (Specifically, I'm using a shim to emulate ES6's Promise object.)  So far, I've faked the window object by adding `global.window = global;` which only gets me so far.  The problem comes in when I want to tear down my fake environment for the next set of tests.

I've tried doing my `require()` calls in the `before()` or `beforeEach()` functions and I've tried manually deleting the created objects in the `after()` or `afterEach()` functions.  One of two things happens each time. Either the global objects persist from one test JS file to the next or the global object are mysteriously absent for all the tests.

I'm not sure if this has to do with the way mocha runs the test JS files or how `require()` works, but I'm out of ideas.  Surely someone has tackled this problem before?

Comment: "*The code I'm testing is meant to be run in a browser*" so why not run it in a browser? Or is that a dumb question?

Comment: @RobG being able to skip the browser lightens the test suite.

Answer (score 0):

You can segregate the "browser code" from the rest of your suite by using Node's [`vm` module](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html). This might be enough for your case. For instance:

```
var vm = require("vm");

var window = {};
window.window = window;

vm.runInNewContext("foo = ['foo val'];", window);
console.log(window.foo);
console.log(window.window.foo);
console.log(window.window.foo === window.foo);
vm.runInNewContext("window.bar = ['bar val'];", window);
console.log(window.bar);
console.log(window.window.bar);
console.log(window.window.bar === window.bar);
```

The documentation on the [contextify package](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify) mentions use cases (asynchronous code) that `vm` can't handle well. In those cases, you'd have to use a tool like `contextify`, which does what `vm` does and has support for asynchronous code.

If you need to run your browser code in an environment that emulates APIs that are typically present in a browser, then there is [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), which I've used with great success to test code that navigates a DOM tree. Jsdom happens to use `contextify` internally to segregate the browser code from the rest of Node.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)

It lets you:

- inject mocks for other modules or globals like process
- leak private variables
- override variables within the module.